# How to assign result of dot product operation into 2 axis of 3D tensor by using double for loop in Python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I'm trying to perform dot product "pixel of RGb image" by "pixel of grayscale image"
And I need to assign result of dot product into 2 axis (last axis) of ori_img
to create "pixel by pixel dot producted" image from np_img_R and np_img_S
Code is as follow

```
# I have (826, 600, 3) 3D tensor, which will be used as final result RGB color image
ori_img=np.zeros((826, 600, 3))

# And I also have (826, 600, 3) 3D tensor np_img_R as RGB color image,
# and (826, 600) 2D matrix np_img_S as grayscale image

# I'd like to perform dot product of 2 axis of np_img_R (3 length list like [x x x])
# and one scalar value of np_img_S indexed by row and column indices
# And I'd like to assign result of dot product into 3 axis of ori_img like [92 22 12]
# So, I used double for loop
for i in range(0,825):
    for j in range(0,599):
        # np_img_R[i,j,:]: select all from last axis
        # np_img_S[i,j]: index by row and column
        # ori_img[i,j,:]: assign result of dot product into last axis
        # to create new image
        ori_img[i,j,:]=np.dot(np_img_R[i,j,:],np_img_S[i,j])


# And I checked whether "result of dot product" and "assigned value in ori_img 3D tensor" are same
print(np.dot(np_img_R[456,232,:],np_img_S[456,232]))
# [130 250 255]
print(ori_img.astype(int)[456,232,:])
# [130 250 255]
# Above results show same result

print(np.dot(np_img_R[825,599,:],np_img_S[825,599]))
[ 50  29 113]
print(ori_img.astype(int)[825,599,:])
[0 0 0]
# But above results show different result, actually ori_img is not assigned by result of dot product

print(np_img_R.shape)
# (826, 600, 3)
print(ori_img.shape)
# (826, 600, 3)
# Shape of both show same
```

I'd like to assign result of dot product into 3 axis of ori_img
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`np.dot()` of a vector and a scalar is just elementwise multiplication](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html). And because NumPy offers broadcasting, there isn't even a need for a double loop. Instead you can just do

```
ori_img = img_R * np_img_S[..., None]
```

Comment: Thanks for good points when using np.dot() and nice solution code.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please remember to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: What is the meaning of a dot product and a scalar in Python? Is the scalar broadcast to a vector? Does that make sense?

Comment: @CrisLuengo It specifically says in the docs: ["If either a or b is 0-D (scalar), it is equivalent to multiply and using numpy.multiply(a, b) or a * b is preferred."](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)

Comment: Thanks. That is really weird though. The dot product should be a scalar.